# trying to pick up my neighbors wifi to my PC. I have my neighbors permission to do this

Tags: wireless-networking

I have purchased a wifi adaptor for my pc and still can't seem to get the wifi in. Once I unplug my regular internet service from the modem, I get nothing. What could be the problem?

Comment: Could be too weak of a signal -- how far away is the neighbor's access point?

Comment: Is the wifi encrypted, and if so are do your encryption setting match the router.  For example open,WEP,WPA,WPA2 or etc.  Do you have the password if there is one?

Answer (score 1):

1) If you live in a house then the WiFi signal is probably too far away.

2) If it is not too far away it could be a compatibility issue.

1a) To find out if the signal is too far away try connecting while at your neighbors house.

2a) One possibility is the router could be set to N only and/or 5GHz only and your adapter is a B and/or G adapter which only runs at 2.4GHz

Note: if it is a USB adapter and does NOT have an external antenna the range it will reach is only about 300 feet and as it passes through walls it will get moderately weaker.